# How to play media via speaker phone

Tags: android, audio

I'm able to play a media using a MediaPlayer.

But how can I play the media with speaker phone only? 
I have tried:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

That does not work. And I have add this to my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Can someone please tell me what am i missing?

Answer (score 11):

setSpeakerphoneOn() only work when audio mode set to MODE_IN_CALL. Try this:

`AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);`

Please remember set back to normal mode before you quit.